# Am I right in thinking there is no way to put an if statement and an else statement on one line in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

Am I right in thinking I can't put an if-statement and the corresponding else-statement on one line in Python?

NB:

```
variable = value1 if condition else value2
```

is NOT two statements. It's one statement which can take the value of one of two *expressions*.

I want to do something like

```
if condition a=value1 else b=value2
```

Am I right in thinking this requires a full if-else in Python? Like

```
if condition:
    a=value1
else:
    b=value2
```

---

**Note** as I already noted above (this is inherent to the definition of what is a statement and what is an expression, with which every programmer should be familiar), because I am I assigning two different variables, the above is quite different to

```
if condition:
    a=value1
else:
    a=value2
```

where I could of course simply use a conditional expression

```
a = value1 if condition else value2
```

Therefore my question is not a duplicate of [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Comment: Out of interest, why would you want to do this?

Comment: Beautiful code. Dozens of short statements like this would look nicer on one line each, than on four lines each!

Comment: If you have dozens of related but distinct variables, I think your code needs refactoring.

Comment: @Talvalin It's not a duplicate! That question is referring to expressions, not statements. This question is very different.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for the advice, but I did not write the functions which I have to pass these variables to. In a perfect world we could refactor everything :)

Comment: "Beautiful code", in my mind, does not include single-line hacks for their own sake. [Readability counts!](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: @HenryKeiter This isn't a hack, dozens of other languages allow this syntax.

Comment: @HenryKeiter For example in C, if (c) {a=b;} else {b=c;} is very readable.

Comment: @Louise Dozens of other languages are more-or-less whitespace agnostic, so in-lining arbitrary code is trivial. In Python, this is a hack.

Comment: Perhaps if you edited your question to include a clear explanation of what you want to do and why we could give better help?

Comment: Don't treat `a` and `b` differently and your problem goes away

Comment: Just out of curiosity in Ruby you can simply achieve this with ternary operator: `condition ? a=value1 : b=value2` .

Comment: The question space is the space for questions. The comment space is the place for comments. Please adhere to this.

Comment: The linked question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Look up the syntax at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement and you will see that the statement parts have to have a NEWLINE token.  But it is not a duplicate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python requires you to put your if and your else on different lines because failure to do so makes your code difficult to read and makes it easy to write unpleasantly unreadable code.

It is unlikely your code will actually be better with this feature.

Instead consider using a function to give a more meaningful aspect to your code, by returning a tuple you can alter both `a` and `b` at the same time.

Comment: thats not at all the answer ... its because assignments dont result in return values ... (the same reason you couldnt do `(print "yellow") if condition else (print "5555)"` )

Comment: @JoranBeasley: No. The OP is talking about the usual control flow `if:` and 'else:` structure not the ternary `a if x else b` operator.

Comment: oh I see ... I guess I didnt get that ... I thought he was just talking about if/else with a single assignment in each branch

Comment: @JoranBeasley why are you using "he"?

Comment: sorry force of habit... usually I say OP

Answer (score 2):

```
my_items = {}
my_items["a" if condition else "b"] = value
```

would be better I would think ...

but you could do

```
globals()["a" if condition else "b"] = value
```

which would do exactly what you are asking (although in general this is frowned upon)

if you wanted to get really gross you could do

```
eval("a=value1" if condition else "b=value2")
```

but I would never ever recommend actually doing something like that

to be honest I have a hard time thinking of any valid use-case where you would actually want

```
if condition:
  a = value1
else:
  b = value2
```

Comment: Thanks! :)
This still isn't two separate statements though, what if I want the value to be conditional too?
Sorry, I gave an overly simplistic example.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't actually recommend it, but you could also use tuple unpacking:

```
a,b = (value1 if condition else a), (value2 if not condition else b)
```

Comment: or shorter: `a,b = value1, b if condition else a, value2`

Comment: Thanks! :) I think this might confuse people though.

Comment: @Louise If you don't want to confuse people, put those statements on separate lines, at least when using Python. Python is whitespace-sensitive for a reason: To improve readability.